# How to receive a message from Tibco EMS with a Spring Boot service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, tibco-ems

I'm new in this topic. I need to create a Java service with **Spring Boot** that receives a message from **TIBCO EMS**, but I have no idea how to start

I just know that I can use **TibjmsConnectionFactory**, but I don't know how to implement that. How would be the method that receives the message? I need to create a `GetMapping` or something like this?

I have the connection data of the service (e.g. url, password, username, destination.queue, reply.queue) and this service uses SSL, but how do I use?

Comment: This question is just too broad & vague. It's not clear if you need help understanding Spring Boot in general or if you already have your basic Spring Boot application and you just need help with Spring JMS integration with Tibco or if you already have basic Spring JMS integration configured and you're having Tibco-specific issues. You need to clarify your issue and narrow the scope *significantly*.

Comment: I have a basic Spring Boot application and I just need help with Spring JMS integration with Tibco

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there about how to use Spring JMS. I recommend you find and follow one of those until you hit a road-block and then ask a specific question about *that*.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should start with the getting started lessons of the spring boot project site, there you will learn how to create a spring boot project from the scratch and also there is getting started lecture for REST-Service which you need to create, so this would be a good start point : https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to receive a message from Tibco EMS with a Spring Boot service. It's just a pointer to a guide to getting started with Spring Boot.